# Increase img size and height onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a function in javascript that will increase the size of the image clicked on. I am not sure why it is not letting me use rem in javascript but when I take rem away the number by itself still doesnt work.

html :

```
<div class="main-textbox-about">
                    <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1" onclick="highlight();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
function highlight() {
    var img = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos")
    img.innerHTML.style.height = 50;
    img.innerHTML.style.width = 40;
}
```

Comment: Because `style` is a property of the `img` element, not the `innerHTML`. Use `img.style.height = 200;`

Comment: @JSheckle can you add a codepen protoype (https://codepen.io/) of what you have so far to your question? If you do, we could reply back with an edited, working prototype.

Comment: @JeromyFrench would github work as codepen.io isnt letting me upload the images

Comment: You don't need to use original images for demo purpose. you can use fake ones from https://placeholder.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a click listener on the container element of images and use event object to get the image that was clicked on and set its width and height.

values of width and height should be strings instead of numbers

```js
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');

imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.style.height = '150px';
  e.target.style.width = '150px';
});
```

```html
<div class="main-textbox-about">
  <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

As per your comment, you only want one big image at a time. You can achieve this by keeping track of previously enlarged image and resetting its width and height whenever there's a click event

```js
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');
let prevEnlargedImg;

imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (prevEnlargedImg) {
    prevEnlargedImg.style.height = '100px';
    prevEnlargedImg.style.width = '100px';
  }

  prevEnlargedImg = e.target;

  e.target.style.height = '150px';
  e.target.style.width = '150px';
});
```

```html
<div class="main-textbox-about">
  <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for! However is there a way to stop the function when I click on the next image, as in only one image is changed in size at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I have stolen an image grid on codepen and added the js for adding the highlight function. I've used the event argument 'e' to access target (element generating the click event) and setting the style directly to it.
Probably you can consider a better approach with css classes, at least.

```
function highlight(e) {
  e.target.style.width="50px";
  e.target.style.height="80px";
}

//This line is just for adding click event using jquery, you don't need it
$('img').on('click', highlight)
```

https://codepen.io/SimCu/pen/abvPOwd